# PHP - Session already started - ignoring session_start (but doesn't do just that)

Tags: php, session, cookies

Does anyone have an explanation for what is going on here?

I have a mainpage, on which I call `session_start()`.
Then I have an PHP script, which is invoked using Ajax.
If I don't put in `session_start()` there, it will not work.
However, if I do, it works just fine, but displaying:

> Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dsb\php\ds_acc.php on line 2

I probably have made a mistake somewhere, but isn't that a paradox? While saying, it ignores that `session_start()`, the script breaks when removing it.
Thank you for your input.

Here the code, sorry if it is a bit obfuscated:

index.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once("php/ds_acc.php");
?>
```

ds_acc.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once("db_login.php");
require_once("permission.php");

if(check_permission("user"))
{   
    if(isset($_REQUEST["action"]))
    {
        switch($_REQUEST["action"])
        {
            case "add":
            add_user();
            break;
        }
    }
}else
{
    echo "error: session invalid";
}

function add_user()
{
}
?>
```

permission.php:

```
<?php
require_once("db_login.php");
/* Returns true if permission is granted, otherwise false. */

function check_permission($required_level)
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION["id"]))
    {
        /* Not logged in */
        return false;
    }

    /* reload banned */
    $con = get_con();
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT banned FROM users WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["id"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($banned);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();

    if($banned == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        return false;
    }


    if($_SESSION["permission"] == "admin")
    {
        return true;
    }

    switch($required_level)
    {
        case "user":
            return true;
        case "mod":
            return ($_SESSION["permission"] == "mod");
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
?>
```

At the time of copying, I now realized that it probably is connected to me including the ds_acc.php file to use it's functions, while also using it to post data via Ajax. I should do that in separate files.

(Well, nvm, stackoverflow does not like php starting tags apparently)
Btw, took me a lot of time to format the code before it let me post it, because the first `<?` in one of my files was intended only 3 spaces `._.`

Comment: Line 1: `<?php session_start(); ?>` then line 2: `<?php // all your other code ?>` making sure there's no BOM, cookie etc. etc. etc. above `<?php`

Comment: @Fred -ii- It's on top of the files in both cases, but same php block.

Comment: *Hm...* bizarro. Can you post your code?

Comment: @Fred -ii- Okay, one moment please.

Comment: @Fred-ii- done, if you are still interested. Like I mentioned, it probably is a bad thing to both include the ds_acc.php file and then invoke it with ajax too. I will fix that, let's see if it works then. Should probably do, because now I get that the session_start warning is shown from my main page, while the ajax call still needs and executes it. Mystery solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is, that I include the php file in my index page, and then also invoke it using ajax.
So it will display the duplicate session error on the page, while it needs the session_start if called via Ajax.

Solution: 
Create a separate file, in which I put all the functions from ds_account.php.
Include the new file in ds_acc.php and in the main page.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for making me review the code and finding the error.

Comment: You're very much welcome, I'm glad to see you found the reason. +1

Answer (score 3):

Check if session is started 1st:

ds_acc.php:

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

require_once("db_login.php");
require_once("permission.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
```

must only be executed once. just write it once on the index.php and remove it from the rest of the php files included on your index.php.